# Fresh OwnCloud Installation Loads Blank White Page

Tags: apache2, lamp, ssl, owncloud-server

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I just installed the latest version of owncloud on my lamp installation located at `/var/www/html/owncloud/`

**Problem:** owncloud serves blank white page at https://someothersite.org/

**Useful Info:** I already have multiple wordpress installations using the OpenSSL certificate pointing to `/var/www/html/` on port 443

I tested my SSL by adding phpmyinfo.php to the `/var/www/html/owncloud/` directory and successfully reached the url `https://someothersite.org/phpmyinfo.php` so the SSL warnings are not causing SSL to block files in the directory.  I suspect the problem are not caused by SSL.

In my `owncloud.conf` file I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName someothersite.org 
    ServerAlias www.someothersite.org 

    # If this is the default configuration file we can use: 'ServerName localhost' or also 'ServerAlias localhost'.

    ServerAdmin info@thesolutiontopoverty.org

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/someothersite.org.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/someothersite.org.access.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud/

    <Directory /var/www/html/owncloud>
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #My Edit
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
</VirtualHost>
```

In my `default-ssl.conf` file I have:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin info@someothersite.org
        ServerName localhost
            ServerAlias localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
                #DP Edit - I disabled these
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

          BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

In my `/etc/hosts` file I have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.0.1   someothersite.org
```

In my `someothersite.org.error.log` I have the following error:

```
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01906: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01909: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01906: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[ssl:warn] [pid 32824] AH01909: someothersite.org:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

Any tips?

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to reuse an SSL certificate. Does the certificate have a wildcard or otherwise make reference to `someothersite.org`?

Comment: Wouldn't the url be `someothersite.org/owncloud` ?

Comment: @Matigo Not sure about the wildcard you mentioned, but the documentroot is /var/www/html/  , I have multiple wordpress sites in the same directory and they all use the same SSL certificate, without me adding any extra info beyond their vhosts.

Comment: @Nmath no. There is a index.php file in the owncloud directory at the same level of phpmyinfo.php

Comment: How do you have a wordpress site at the same URL as owncloud?  Wouldn't that cause a problem?  Perhaps the problem you are experiencing?